# Base URL getting appended to end or URL and causing 404's

Tags: url

I have a magento installation (migration) which has been working fine and then suddenly it is adding the base url to the end of urls.

I have checked the database base url entries - all fine
I have checked the .htaccess file - all fine

In fact changing these makes no difference whatever. I am unsure whether the host or the client has made changes, client says not.

Any ideas what this maybe? It's only a demo site at this moment so not uber critical but it's bugging me what it can be.

I've even tried remigrating the old database incase a setting had been changed.

Here's the url: http://baobab.getdoji.co.uk/baobab.getdoji.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of the community after some googling around I found an obscure blog post that held the answer, here it is.

If you migrate Magento you need to change the permissions of the var folder and cache folders to 777 otherwise Magento will aggressively cache in the `/tmp/` folder and this will cause the above problems

Hope this is of help to someone in the future.

Comment: Also found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529059/magento-core-config-data-cache